# Using Azure Function to redirect URL and params to another HTTP Server )Py)

Tags: python, function, azure-functions

I have been working on trying to write an Azure Function that does the following:

A client/browser makes a request to `https://foo.azurewebsites.com/$A/$B`.  An example could look like `http://foo.azurewebsites.com/john/30vjs0-s9fjs-fnsne`.

`$A` = one of up to 20 possible dictionary words.

`$B` = unknown strings, but the strings need to be passed onto the secondary server too.

I would like to redirect that entire HTTP request (GET and POST ideally) to another HTTP server (outside Az).

I understand I need to make separate functions for each one of `$A`, (each with effectively the same code inside) to redirect it to the other HTTP server.  However I can't seem to figure out how to parse the URL correctly in Python within the Az Functions modules.  It is dealing with the unknown variables in $B that is causing the problem I believe, as I can't hardcode them as I cannot predict them. Az Functions currently doesn't pass anything that doesn't exactly match the `/functionName` argument - but in my use case there will always be a `$B`.

So `https://foo.azurewebsites.com/john` will be forwarded to my seocondary server, but `https://foo.azurewebsites.com/john/test.txt` appears to be being dropped by Az.

My Python to forward on GET and POST is here (repeated for each function in the list of $A): I have been experiementing mainly with GET requests.

```
def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    if req.method == "GET":
        return get(req)
    if req.method == "POST":
        return post(req)

def post(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
       
    header_dict = {}
    get_url = 'https://secondaryserver.com'
    for key, value in dict(req.headers).items():
        header_dict.update({key : value})
   
    post_data = req.get_body()
    request = urllib.request.Request(get_url, data=post_data, headers=header_dict)
    with urllib.request.urlopen(request) as response:
        html = response.read()
    return func.HttpResponse(html)


def get(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    suffix = req.url
    get_url = 'https://secondaryserver.com'
    final_url = get_url + suffix
    header_dict = {}
    print(final_url)
    for key, value in dict(req.headers).items():
        header_dict.update({key : value})
    request = urllib.request.Request(final_url, headers=header_dict)
    with urllib.request.urlopen(request) as response:
        html = response.read()
    return func.HttpResponse(html)
```

I have also investigated this article from Microsoft, trying "route": {url} in my function.json and then referencing it in the Python **init**.py but was unsuccessful (and Az reported the trigger URLS as `%7BURL%7B`

**I guess a key question is 'is this actually possible on Az Functions - to pass parameters AFTER the name of a function within an app, and have that able to be referenced in Python code?**

Thank you for any help you might be able to provide.

Comment: Is that you want to route all path to the function?

Comment: Hello there,

If I can have just ONE function that can deal with any of the possible options for $A and $B, that will work. But I think I need separate functions to deal with each of the possibilities for $A.

So yes, I need to route all paths to the each function:

/api/john/AnyPossibleString to the function, and the same for /api/bob/AnyPossiblestring to a separate function (that actually does the same, just re-routes to the secondary server.

I guess I am aiming to have an almost 'socat' dumb redirector for HTTP traffic  in an Azure Function :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to route some request path to the same function, you can define the `route` in the `function.json`. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=csharp#customize-the-http-endpoint).

For example. I want to route `https://{}/$A/$B` to the same function. We should define the `function.json` as below

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": ["get", "post"],
      "route": "{url}/{url1}"
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "$return"
    }
  ]
}
```

Test

My function code

```
def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
   

    
    return func.HttpResponse(
             req.url,
             status_code=200
        )
```

### [image]
[image]

**Update**

If you want to forward the request to another HTTP server, you can refer to the following code

```
def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    if req.method == "GET":
        # send you request
    if req.method == "POST":
         # send you request
```

Comment: Hello - thank you for your comment.  I did not notice that if you have a function called blahblah, but with {url}/{url1} that it would route without calling /blahblah/etc

I have tested, and you need to have the correct number of {url} objects, as {url}/{url1} would error if a string of /foor/bar/test was sent to the Function.  I THINK can ensure that only a known number of {url} are used

Thank you for answering that part of the question :) Do you have any guidance on the best way of forwarding all GET / POST to the secondary server, receiving the output and sending it back to the client?

Answer (score 2):

To redirect a URL from Azure Functions (python), use the following `return` statement with a status code of 302 with the new redirection URL stored in `RedirectionURL` variable

```
return func.HttpResponse(RedirectionURL,headers={'Location': RedirectionURL},status_code=302)
```